# nbconvert no longer working with nbextensions

Tags: jupyter, nbconvert

I recently had to do a complete reinstall of jupyter on my machine. Since then, when I use nbextensions to convert my notebooks to an html file, the table of contents links to the original notebook rather than the new html file. Before, the basic command `jupyter nbconvert --to html mynotebook.ipynb` produced a functional table of contents.

Unfortunately, I have no idea why toc2 is no longer properly converting to HTML. I will appreciate any insights that anyone can give me.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was a bug introduced to toc2 by a recent update. toc2 has since been updated to fix this issue.